# CalendarDatePicker inside Button flyout

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I want to use CalendarDatePicker inside Button flyout like this:

```
<Button>
   <Button.Flyout>
      <Flyout>
         <StackPanel>
             <CalendarDatePicker x:Name="calendar"></CalendarDatePicker>                                          
             <Button Click="Button_Click">Save</Button>
         </StackPanel>
      </Flyout>
   </Button.Flyout>
</Button>
```

But when I click on calendar whole Flyout disappears. I targeting Windows 10 UWP app. Any ideas how to solve it? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You probably won't be able to use *CalendarDatePicker* inside the *Flyout* - flyout is closed as soon as you choose one option, in this case once you click control to show calendar, the flyout is closed along with opened calendar (you may even see it for a while if you hold a control). In this case you can use for example *Popup* or *ContentDialog*.

XAML:

```xml
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Button Name="showCalndarButton" Content="Show PopUP" Click="showCalndarButton_Click"/>
    <Popup Name="calendarPopup">
        <StackPanel>
            <CalendarDatePicker x:Name="calendar"></CalendarDatePicker>
            <Button Click="Button_Click">Save</Button>
        </StackPanel>
    </Popup>

    <ContentDialog Name="calendarDialog">
        <StackPanel>
            <CalendarDatePicker x:Name="secondCalendar"></CalendarDatePicker>
            <Button Click="Button_Click">Save</Button>
        </StackPanel>
    </ContentDialog>
</Grid>
```

Code behind:

```cs
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // some logic

    // calendarPopup.IsOpen = false;
    calendarDialog.Hide();
}

private async void showCalndarButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // calendarPopup.IsOpen = true;
    await calendarDialog.ShowAsync();
}
```

In this case - both *ContentDialog* and *Popup*, you will have to design yourself.

Comment: OK and what if button is inside ListView DataTemplate?

Comment: @Vodáček I think you should be able to expose click event from datatemplate, where your listview is defined, and do the same. You can probably also build a UserControl for datatemplate.